# data transformation with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a input dataframe df1 like this.

```
      account_id            Product           prod_code                        cost            Account
0     12345                 COMMON            AWSCloudTrail                    1               AU-MGT
1     12345                 COMMON                  AWSGlue                    2               AU-MGT
2     12345                 COMMON            AWSQueueService                  1               AU-MGT
3     12345                 COMMON          AWSSecretsManager                  1               AU-MGT
4     12345                 COMMON             AmazonDynamoDB                  1               AU-MGT
5     12345                 prod1            emr                               4.5             AU-MGT
6     12345                 prod2            ec2                               6.5             AU-MGT
5     12345                 prod1            S3                                2.5             AU-MGT
6     12345                 prod2            KMS                               3.5             AU-MGT
```

I have another dataframe df_allocation, where I am giving some percentage.Basically total 'COMMON' cost for AU_MGT account in the example ($6) from df1 goes into different product based on this percentage

```
Product AU-MGT  AU-STG  AU-PRD  
prod1   20      60      70  
prod2   80      40      30
```

I need a output dataframe which will same structure like df1 where there will no records for Product='COMMON'. 'COMMON' cost will be splitted across different account, product and prod_code. Output dataframe: **df_output**

```
    account_id            Product           prod_code                        cost            Account
1     12345                 prod1            emr                               5.1             AU-MGT
2     12345                 prod2            ec2                               8.9             AU-MGT
3     12345                 prod1            S3                                3.1             AU-MGT
4     12345                 prod2            KMS                               5.9             AU-MGT
```

**Calculation:**
$6 COMMON cost

```
prod1 = 6 * 20 % = $1.2
PROD2 = 6 * 80 % = $4.8
```

for this example:
prod1 has 2 different prod_code emr and s3 so 50-50 allocation

```
emr-> 4.5+(1.2/2)=5.1 s3->2.5 + (1.2/2) = 3.1
```

prod2 has 2 different prod_code ec2 and kms so 50-50 allocation

```
ec2-> 6.5+ (4.8/2) = 8.9  kms-> 3.5 + (4.8/2) = 5.9
```

How can I achieve this using pandas? In the input I have multiple account id and product. Total cost should be matched .This example in df1 total cost for AU_MGT account is 23 $ which exactly matches with df_output total cost

Answer (score 0):

The key is to reshape your second dataframe to be compatible with your first dataframe:

```
is_common = df1['Product'] == 'COMMON'

# Reshape your dataframe
prod = df2.set_index('Product').rename_axis(columns='Account').stack().rename('Percent')

# Cost: 6.0
common_cost = df1[is_common].groupby('Account')['cost'].sum().rename('common_cost')

# Num product: 50-50
num_product = df1[~is_common].groupby(['Product', 'Account']).size().rename('num_prod')

# Add columns 'common_cost' and 'num_prod'
prod = prod.to_frame() \
           .join(common_cost, on='Account') \
           .join(num_product, on=['Product', 'Account'])

# Compute additional cost for each product for each account
add_cost = prod['common_cost'] * prod['Percent'] / 100 / prod['num_prod']
add_cost = add_cost.rename('add_cost')

# Get the final cost
df1 = df1.merge(add_cost, on=['Product', 'Account'])
df1['total_cost'] = df1['cost'] + df1['add_cost']
```

```
>>> df1
   account_id Product prod_code  cost Account  add_cost  total_cost
0       12345   prod1       emr   4.5  AU-MGT       0.6         5.1
1       12345   prod1        S3   2.5  AU-MGT       0.6         3.1
2       12345   prod2       ec2   6.5  AU-MGT       2.4         8.9
3       12345   prod2       KMS   3.5  AU-MGT       2.4         5.9
```